# How do I hide entire row if a certain cell in that row is empty?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html-table

I've been stuck with this for a while now. How do I hide a row if the second columns (svar) cell is empty on all rows where the cells under svar is not filled in?

Here is my code so far:

**PHP**

```
$localhost = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

$connect = mysqli_connect($localhost, $username, $password)or 
die("Kunde inte koppla");

mysqli_select_db($connect, 'wildfire');

$result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM question");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Fråga</th>
<th>Svar</th>
<th>Poäng</th>
<th>Redigera</th>
<th>Radera</th>
<th>AID</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['qid'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['answer'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Point'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><a href=\"editdilemman.php?aid=".$row['aid']."\">Redigera</a></td>";
echo "<td><a href=\"radera.php?id=".$row['aid']."\">Ta bort</a></td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['aid'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($connect);
```

**JQuery**

```
 var t = $('table').parent().children().find("td:nth-child(2):empty").parent().hide();
```

Comment: why are you doing unnecessarily parent().children() ??? Just do this: `$('table').find("td:nth-child(2):empty").parent().hide();`

Comment: Yes svar=answer, sorry I didnt clarify it before

Comment: So what about just updating the query to not select unneeded records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would update the query so you only return the records you want displayed. So change:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM question");
```

to

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM question where answer <> '' && answer IS NOT NULL");
```

Comment: Agreed with this as you dont need client side code for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$('td:nth-child(2):empty').closest('tr').hide();
```

Here is the [`FIDDLE`](https://jsfiddle.net/nyjv2ogx/).